# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, is $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid X\le Y)=\mathbb{E}(f(X))$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This could be a stupid question, but here goes.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, is $\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid X\le Y)=\mathbb{E}(f(X))$?

The answer depends on the sigma algebras generated by the event $X\le Y$ and I do not think they are independent of $X$.

Comment: Of course not--take for example Y constant.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** No.

Take $Y=0$, $f$ identity function, and $X$ discrete with $P(X=-1) = 0.3$ and $P(X=1)=0.7$. Note that:

$$E\left[X \; \mid \; X\leq 0\right] = \frac{E\left[X1_{X\leq 0}\right] }{P(X\leq 0)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you are looking for this kind of answer or not, but here it is.
For simplicity,I will consider discrete random variables.

Let $B:=\left\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq Y(\omega)   \right\}$ and $A_x:=\left\{\omega:X(\omega)=x  \right\}$.
Left-hand side is,
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X)\mid B)=\sum_{x}f(x)P(X=x\mid B)=\sum_x f(x) P(A_x\cap B),
$$

and right-hand side is ,

$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X))=\sum_xf(x) P(X=x)=\sum_xf(x)P(A_x).
$$
So, your claim is true so long as $A_x\subset B$ for all $x$

Comment: ...You mean, as long as $A_x\subset B$ *for every* $x$, right? That is, if $P(X\leqslant Y)=1$. That is, if there is no conditioning. :-)

Comment: @Did Indeed, thanks for pointing that out.